# Variables set to true wont go into while loop java

Tags: java, while-loop

I need some helping figuring out a problem with writing Boolean expressions in my code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Dudo

{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // raise call  spot on  pass
        Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
        boolean player1;
        boolean player2;        
        int dicep1 = 5;
        int dicep2 = 5;
        Random rand = new Random();
        int  n = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
        int  y = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
        System.out.println("Welcome to Dudo!");
        System.out.println("Rolling to see who goes first");
        {

            if (n > y )
            {
                System.out.println("Player 1 goes first");  
            }
            else if (n < y)
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 goes first");
            }
            else if (n == y)
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 goes first");
            }
            int[] Array;
            Array = new int [dicep1];
            for(int i=0;i<Array.length;i++)
            {
                Array[i] = randomFill();
            }

            int[] Array2;
            Array2 = new int [dicep2];
            for(int j=0;j<Array2.length;j++)
            {
                Array2[j] = randomFill2();
            }
            player1 = true;
            player2 = true;


            while ((player1 == true) && (player2 == true));
            {
                System.out.println("Player 1, your numbers are....." + Arrays.toString(Array)); 
                System.out.println("Player 2, your numbers are....." + Arrays.toString(Array2));
            }
            if ((player1 = false) || (player2 = false));
            {

            }
        }
    }               



    private static int randomFill2()
    {
        int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 6 + 1);
        return randomNum;
    }

    private static int randomFill() 
    {
        int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 6 + 1);
        return randomNum;
    }

}
```

player1 and player2 are both set to `true`:

```
player1 = true;
player2 = true;
```

When the code is executed, the while loop doesn't recognize that both the variables are `true` and doesn't show the output, in this case, the numbers the players rolled for their five dice

```
while ((player1 == true) && (player2 == true));
{
    System.out.println("Player 1, your numbers are....." + Arrays.toString(Array)); 
    System.out.println("Player 2, your numbers are....." + Arrays.toString(Array2));
}
```

I've tried changing the way it is written multiple times yet I can not get anything inside the `while` bracket to output

Why is it doing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: `while ((player1 == true) && (player2 == true));` - remove the `;`

Comment: wow thanks a lot it was that simple

Comment: The real question is, why is this in a `while` loop to begin with?

Comment: Now that you mention it, it makes no sense for me to even have that. Thanks for the observation

Comment: And why all the `else`s? The computation is simply `if (n > y) /*player 1 goes first*/ else /*player 2 goes first*/`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a semi-colon after your `while` loop (note this same problem occurs with your following `if` statement). This causes the loop body to be empty. The brackets afterwards simply [define a new scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484884/java-just-curly-braces).

E.g. your code is treated as:

```
while ((player1 == true) && (player2 == true)){/*do nothing*/}
//in a new (nested) scope do:
System.out.println("Player 1, your numbers are....." + Arrays.toString(Array)); 
System.out.println("Player 2, your numbers are....." + Arrays.toString(Array2));
```

---

Not sure why you have these statements in a `while` loop at all though, it should probably be an `if` statement. Currently, this will print these things forever since there's nothing inside to break out of the loop...

Comment: @JAKoharik, if this answer solved your problem, you can [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)